# AngularJS directive to add content after element and trigger element click

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to create a very simple directive to ask confirmation on a button click.

The following html:

```
<button kr-confirm>Delete</button>
```

Should compile into:

```
<button kr-confirm>Delete</button>
<span ng-show="vm.isOpen"> 
   Are you sure?
   <span class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Yes</span>
   <span class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">No</span>
</span>
```

I wanted to handle this in `templateUrl`, but could not find an option to add template after element.

I ended up adding DOM in `link` function and calling `element.on('click')` but this doesn't seem to work.

Based on HTML and anticipated result, how would I go about implementing this?

Best case would be if it could be solved with `templateUrl`.

See my current fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kraaness/4rn8ycb3/

Comment: I'm using 1.6.x - sorry for the confusion. JS Fiddle specifies the wrong version

Comment: I'm not clear why you abandoned a standard template, which should simply replace your directive element (not be appended to it).

Comment: That was my initial attempt, but couldn't get it to work. I want to pass all the attributes of the primary element. However, when the directive is replaced, all attributes are copied to the root element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a component that will provide you with the desired functionality. See a quick `<confirmation-button>` component below.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .component('confirmationButton', {
    bindings: {
      onConfirm: '&'
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="$ctrl.confirm = true">Delete</button>' +
      '<div ng-show="$ctrl.confirm">Are you sure?' +
      '<button ng-click="$ctrl.onConfirm(); $ctrl.confirm = false">Yes</button>' +
      '<button ng-click="$ctrl.confirm = false">No</button></div>'
  })
  .run(function($rootScope) { // using $rootScope just for sake of the demo
    $rootScope.delete = function() {
      alert("Oh no!");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <confirmation-button on-confirm="delete()"></confirmation-button>
</div>
```

Comment: My question was incomplete and this is the accepted answer based on the information given. Thank you !